# How to generate plasma above 10^6 K without using neutral beam injection.

Tags: fusion

I want to make a model Tokamak fusion reactor to experiment with and toy around. I am willing to sink some money into its construction, but I cannot afford a neutral beam injector to heat the plasma. Is their another way to heat the plasma to any temperature comparable to what is needed that will not cost all the money I have.

Comment: Well, given that your energy losses will be larger (proportionally) in a small system, you are going to need to be able to pump lots of power into it.

Comment: and how would I achieve that with out spending an arm and a leg?

Comment: Well, you probably wouldn't, of course. (If 1,000,000K plasmas were cheap, everyone would have one! Well, maybe not everyone...).

Comment: Well at least I know now, much appreciated

Comment: if you specify *some money* (at least in order of magnitudes) we can tell you if this is feasible

Comment: okay I can spend up to $15,000

Comment: look into pyroelectric fusion. It will not produce enough fusion on its own, but it will produce enough neutrons to heat your plasma (all precautions should be taken, as long term exposure of any environment with neutrons will accumulate and render your work environment hazardous for your health and the environment )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned a temperature of $10^6\,\mathrm{K}$ which corresponds to a thermal energy of approximately $100\,\mathrm{eV}$ - it is common in plasma physics to simply refer to this value as temperature.

To achieve a temperature of $100\,\mathrm{eV}$ in a typical tokamak, you do not need any additional heating method: keep in mind that you already have Ohmic heating. That is heating due to the inductively driven current, an inherent feature of every tokamak.

Ohmic heating is not sufficient to achieve fusion, but sufficient to achieve $100\,\mathrm{eV}$. That is good for you as you do not need to buy external heating sources.

Things you need to "sink some money into":

1. Vacuum vessel
2. Vacuum pumps
3. Magnetic field coils
4. Power supplies

You are looking for a toroidal vacuum vessel and it will be tough to find a used one. If you are lucky, you can get one from no longer used experiments (ask universities which have plasma physics groups), but most likely you need to construct one. Keeping the number of ports to a minimum you might end up spending $100\,$k€ if ordering such a vacuum vessel at a manufacturer (I am assuming here that it fits on two large tables, i.e. a *table-top-device*). But maybe you are good in building such a stainless steel device on your own, then a few k€ should be fine.

You need good vacuum to achieve breakdown and I would estimate something like $10\,$k€ for a cheap turbo molecular pump. Look for used pumps, you can probably save some money.

Copper coils can be expensive, I would estimate $10-30\,$k€. You have, however, good chances to get used coils if you know some people working in university labs. I have seen coils lying around and not being used in quite a few labs. I would not be surprised if you can just borrow them for free (they are hard to break).

Power supplies can again be expensive when buying new models, easy to spend a few $10\,$k€. But there exists a market for old models where you can save quite a bit.

Summing it up, for a small table-top-tokamak with $100\,\mathrm{eV}$ I guess you would need a few thousand Euro if you are very well connected and are able to build and construct things on your own. It would get significantly more expensive if you want to buy all new components.

*Warning*: the list given above is certainly not complete, feel free to correct me and please tell me if you have the feeling I missed something important.

Comment: I really appreciate the detailed advice. Luckily I am connected with a big university, and I do have some capital that I am willing to spend.

Comment: @ConradG being connected to a big university is certainly helpful. I've seen it happen very often that if a lab gets a new toroidal confinement device, the old device is given away for free to some other university. So you might be the one putting the old experiment back into operation. To get an idea where tokamaks are/were operated, have a look here: [http://www.tokamak.info/](http://www.tokamak.info/)

Comment: Dear sir, you are a hero.

Comment: @ConradG feel free to accept the answer as a solution :)

Comment: The first part of the answer, about Ohmic heating, is correct. Even H-mode is possible with Ohmic heating. The rest sounds about right, too. You should accept this answer.